# Tricky passage from Daudet

Tags: traduction

J'ai du mal à comprendre, et donc traduire, l'extrait suivant des *« Notes sur la vie »* d'Alphonse Daudet :

> J'ai le sentiment du ridicule poussé loin. Le ridicule me fait mal, je ris, mais je souffre ; il me choque sur moi du reste, comme sur les autres.

Je traduirais :

> I have a well-developed sense of ridicule. Ridicule hurts me: I laugh, but I suffer.

C'est la phrase finale qui me pose problème.

Comment: Bienvenue sur FL. On ne peut pas t'aider à traduire du français dans une langue étrangère ((Voir le [Help centre](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)), mais bien sûr sit tu dis exactement [avec précision](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) ce que tu ne comprends pas et pourquoi, dans le morceau de phrase, quelqu'un pourra peut-être l'expliquer.

Comment: _il me choque sur moi, comme sur les autres_: je pense que _sur moi_ signifie: _quand il s'agit de moi_ (et _comme sur les autres_ = _quand il s'agit des autres_). Daudet est choqué par le ridicule quand il s'agit de lui-même, aussi bien que quand il s'agit des autres.

Answer (score 7):

*Il me choque sur moi, comme sur les autres*: je pense que *sur moi* signifie: *quand il s'agit de moi* (et *comme sur les autres = quand il s'agit des autres*). Daudet est choqué par le ridicule quand il s'agit de lui-même, aussi bien que quand il s'agit des autres.